# Before / after insert trigger using auto increment field

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm having troubles with an insert trigger that is supposed to fix a column in a table:

```
id        - auto increment int
thread_id - int [NULL]
```

What I want to achieve is to set the `thread_id` to `id` if it's inserted as NULL. I have failed because:

- using `before insert` trigger still does not have the new value for `id` and mysteriously sets `thread_id` to 0
- using `after insert - update` trigger throws reasonable exception `can't update table because it is already used by the statement`.
- you can not add additional auto increment field

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON yourtable 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

SET NEW.thread_id = IF(ISNULL(NEW.thread_id), 0, NEW.thread_id);

END;

$$
```

Edit: in order to modify values of the current record, you don't use UPDATE statement, you access them by using `NEW.columname`

Comment: This doesn't set `thread_id` to `id`, though.  If it tried, it'd run into the same problem as the OP is asking about; before the actual insert, `NEW.id` is 0, and after it you can't modify `NEW` (cause it's already been stored) or update the table (because it's still in use).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to get the new increment value is not a fancy form. I assumed that you are inserting a new value, so it is suppose to be the maximum id + 1:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON yourtable 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.thread_id = IF(
ISNULL(NEW.thread_id), 
(SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM yourtable), 
NEW.thread_id);
END;
```

It worked for my case, if it's NULL it will get the max ID + 1, which will be the new id.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
the code below is not working :

```sql
    `DELIMITER #
CREATE DEFINER='user'@'server' TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
       FOR EACH ROW 
       BEGIN
       INSERT INTO mytable (thread_id) VALUES (NEW.thread_id);
       END#
DELIMITER ;`
```

This way, the `thread_id` field is set to 0 and the `id` field (PK AUTO INCREMENT) is set to the `thread_id` value (who's the id PK AI from the listening table).

indeed, the AI field is not defined in the INSERT. I solved the problem the way below:

```sql
    `DELIMITER #
CREATE DEFINER='user'@'server' TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER INSERT ON mytable
       FOR EACH ROW 
       BEGIN
       INSERT INTO mytable (id, thread_id) VALUES (null, NEW.thread_id);
       END#
DELIMITER ;`
```

Stating the PK `id` field and `null` value, the AI problem disappears.
I also replaced `BEFORE` by `AFTER` but i'm not sure this modification is necessary to solve the problem. I didn't test if keeping `BEFORE`  with the other modification solve the problem at all.

Comment: A trigger can't insert into the same table that's triggering on. That will cause an infinite loop.