# MySQL trigger On Insert/Update events

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, insert-update

So I have two tables like this...

```
ext_words
-------------
| id | word |
-------------
| 1  | this |
-------------
| 2  | that |
-------------
| 3  | this |
-------------

ext_words_count
---------------------
| id | word | count |
---------------------
| 1  | this |   2   |
---------------------
| 2  | that |   1   |
---------------------
```

I am trying to create a trigger that will:

- update `ext_words_count.count` when `ext_words.word` is updated.

To further complicate matters,

- if `ext_words.word` does not exist in `ext_words_count` when `ext_words` is updated, I would like to insert it into `ext_words_count` and set `count` as 1.

I have been looking at similar questions:
1.  [Before / after insert trigger using auto increment field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991464/before-after-insert-trigger-using-auto-increment-field?rq=1), and
2.  [Using Trigger to update table in another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910617/using-trigger-to-update-table-in-another-database?rq=1)
trying to combine the 2. Here is what I have so far:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_count
AFTER UPDATE ON ext_words
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  UPDATE ext_words_count
    SET word_count = word_count + 1
  WHERE word = NEW.word;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any advice and direction is greatly appreciated. Or possibly another method that I have overlooked and as always thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I have opted for using 2 triggers, one for INSERT and one for UPDATE because I am not that familiar with conditional statements in MySQL.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insert_word AFTER INSERT ON ext_words
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      INSERT IGNORE INTO ext_words_count (word) VALUES (NEW.word);
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_word AFTER UPDATE ON ext_words
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      UPDATE ext_words_count 
      SET word_count = word_count + 1 
      WHERE word = NEW.word;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The INSERT query is working great, however the UPDATE query is not updating `word_count`. Is there something I missed in the update query..?

Comment: You may like to view this, [MySQL Fire Trigger for both Insert and Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318224/mysql-fire-trigger-for-both-insert-and-update)  Did my solution worked ? What was the result I would like to improve. Remember you can't update same table on which you calls trigger in MySQL

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Thanks for the link! I am not able to get your answer working, but that is because I am new to conditional statements in MySQL, not because of your solution.

Comment: I mean that when ext_words is updated, if the word is not in ext_words_count then I want to insert it and make the count 1. Otherwise if the word is in ext_words_count, increase the count by 1...

Comment: Got it of-course for this my query will not work wait...

Comment: I have a quick question here. If you are storing the words in comma seperated form in some other table like "this, that", can we write a trigger on this table to split the value and store it in ext_words and ext_words_count?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With Grijesh's perfect help and his suggestion to use conditional statements, I  was able to get **ONE** trigger that does both tasks. Thanks again Grijesh

```
 DELIMITER $$ 
 CREATE TRIGGER update_count AFTER INSERT ON ext_words 
 FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
     IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ext_words_count WHERE word = NEW.word) THEN
       INSERT INTO ext_words_count (word) VALUES (NEW.word);
   ELSE
       UPDATE ext_words_count SET word_count = word_count + 1 WHERE word = NEW.word;
   END IF;
  END $$    
 DELIMITER;
```

Comment: nice So which form helped you DB.exchange?

Comment: Never heard from anyone. :( I was just browsing through some of the articles. Thanks again for all of your help and pointing me to the other site!

Comment: This trigger works fantastically in my MySQL server to filter out redundant inserts.

Answer (score 4):

avoid use of keywords like count as its is used by the sql method 
some time its create error but some runs good

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER update_count
   AFTER UPDATE ON ext_words
     FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN

          SELECT count INTO @x FROM ext_words_count LIMIT 1;
          UPDATE ext_words_count
          SET count = @x + 1
          WHERE word = NEW.word;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```