# MySQL select count rows for each unique item in column

Tags: mysql, inner-join

It's easiest to explain by way of an example. Lets say I have a table with 3 columns - father, their offspring and their childs sex. The result table will list the fathers number of children and the split of males and females.

This is the table:

```
Father   Child    Sex
-----------------------
alpha    name1    m
alpha    name2    f
alpha    name3    m
alpha    name4    f
alpha    name5    f
beta     name6    m
beta     name7    m
charlie  name8    f
charlie  name9    m
```

Desired result:

```
Father   num   m    f
-----------------------
alpha    5     2    3
beta     2     2    0
charlie  2     1    1

num = number of children
m = male, f = female
```

When I use count it gives me the the total amount of children from all fathers and I'm not sure how to split the results into male and female.
Any ideas?

Comment: Show the sql statement you used that is returning the wrong counts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    Father,
    COUNT(child) AS total_child, 
    SUM(IF(Sex = 'm', 1, 0)) AS total_m,
    SUM(IF(Sex = 'f', 1, 0)) AS total_f
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    Father
```

Comment: @RobertRozas thanks to correct typo...but yet not test.

Comment: Grijesh and I go way back. He's your guy for SQL. I made [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9be0c/3) just for fun.

Comment: @Drewness thanks :) I was thinking [I know you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975877/mysql-trigger-on-insert-update-events)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Oh yeah buddy! From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975877/mysql-trigger-on-insert-update-events). :)

Comment: Good guy @Drewness xD

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select distinc t.Father, 
(select count(1) from table t1 where t1.Father = t.Father) as num,
(select count(1) from table t1 where t1.Father = t.Father and Sex = 'm') as m,
(select count(1) from table t1 where t1.Father = t.Father and Sex = 'f') as f
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `SUM()` around a boolean variable.

```
SELECT Father, COUNT(Child) as num, SUM(Sex='m') as m, SUM(Sex='f') as f
FROM table
GROUP BY Father;
```