# Trigger that Inserts to another table when new record added

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables. The Data of profit table will come from the bet table. Therefore, automating INSERT to profit table whenever new record got added on bet table will be convenient.

How can I make sure the trigger will insert only data that doesn't exist on the profit table?

Here's what I did so far

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tsuika $$
CREATE TRIGGER keisan BEFORE INSERT ON profitdb
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO `profitdb`(`BetID`,`DateTime`, `PlayerID`,
`Profit`,`SubAgentID`,`SubAgentRisk`,`AgentID`,`AgentRisk`)
SELECT `betdb`.`BetID`,`betdb`.`DateTime`,`betdb`.`PlayerID`,
(`BetAmount`-Payout`),`playerdb`.`SubAgentID`,`subagentdb`.`Risk`,
`agentdb`.`AgentID`,`agentdb`.`Risk` FROM `betdb` LEFT JOIN `playerdb` ON
`betdb`.`PlayerID` = `playerdb`.`PlayerID` LEFT JOIN `subagentdb` ON
`subagentdb`.`SubAgentID` = `playerdb`.`SubAgentID` LEFT JOIN `agentdb` ON
`agentdb`.`AgentID` = `playerdb`.`AgentID`
END
$$
DELIMITER;
```

I referred to this link [MySQL trigger On Insert/Update events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975877/mysql-trigger-on-insert-update-events) regarding making triggers with INSERT but still getting this error

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 5`

Answer (score 0):

You must end all executable statements with *default delimiter*, i.e. `';'` semi-colon in a code block.
You missed a semi-colon after `select` statement.

And you are trying to drop an irrelevant trigger `'tsuika'`. It should be the current trigger you are trying to create or re-define. Change it to `'keisan'`.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS keisan; $$ -- <--- this was with wrong trigger name. corrected.

CREATE TRIGGER keisan BEFORE INSERT ON profitdb
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `profitdb`(`BetID`,`DateTime`, `PlayerID`, `Profit`,  
                         `SubAgentID`,`SubAgentRisk`,`AgentID`,`AgentRisk`)
         SELECT `betdb`.`BetID`, `betdb`.`DateTime`, `betdb`.`PlayerID`,
                ( `BetAmount` - `Payout` ), `playerdb`.`SubAgentID`,
                `subagentdb`.`Risk`, `agentdb`.`AgentID`, `agentdb`.`Risk` 
           FROM `betdb` 
                 LEFT JOIN `playerdb` 
                        ON `betdb`.`PlayerID` = `playerdb`.`PlayerID` 
                 LEFT JOIN `subagentdb` 
                        ON `subagentdb`.`SubAgentID` = `playerdb`.`SubAgentID` 
                 LEFT JOIN `agentdb` 
                        ON `agentdb`.`AgentID` = `playerdb`.`AgentID`; -- <--- missed
END;

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your drop trigger statement is wrong. Change it to `drop trigger if exists keisan;`

Comment: I corrected the part `CREATE TRIGGER keisan...` to `CREATE TRIGGER tsuika...` but still get the error `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'`

Comment: It means that your trigger is not dropped. Drop a relevant trigger if exists. Check my updated answer.

Comment: the table has no triggers and the intended name is tsuika, so I used tsuika.

Comment: What is the output for `drop trigger tsuika;` without using `if exists`.

Comment: btw the target table named profit has triggers, does it affect this?

Comment: No. It should not. By the way are you trying to define `insert trigger` on the same table in which you are executing another `insert` in the trigger body? If yes, it is not going to work. It should just have `set ...` statements.

Comment: I'm defining the trigger in the bet table, and without `drop trigger` this shows `#1360 - Trigger does not exist `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56260/discussion-between-ravinder-and-setsuna).