# MySQL triggers data copy

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger which looks like this:

```
delimiter //
 create trigger tracker after insert on Items for each row
      begin

      end; //
delimiter ;
```

I need to insert `id`, `type`, and `date_created` of the inserted column to another table as

```
INSERT INTO Tracker (table_id, type, date) VALUES ( ??? );
```

I'm not sure how to get those data fields within a trigger. Could someone give me a tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NEW.column_name` to get the inserted value within a trigger

```
INSERT INTO Tracker (table_id, type, date)
VALUES ( NEW.id_col_traker,NEW.col,NEW.col );
```

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access
>   columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL
>   extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive.

[`Trigger Syntax and Examples`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use the NEW alias as it is shown in

[MySQL trigger On Insert/Update events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975877/mysql-trigger-on-insert-update-events)

As an example
    CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON account
     FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount;