# MySQL trigger with conditions on UPDATE

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to insert a conditional type of update in a mysql trigger?  If I need to do something after a certain type of update, for example if the update is a certain type of changing in field value. Better said, if I need to increment a value in another table after that a specific field in my original table changes his value to a specific value, is it possible? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
I'm trying this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Increment 
AFTER UPDATE ON Subscription
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE USER
SET num_sub=num_sub+1
IF NEW.State <> OLD.State AND NEW.STATE='C'
END IF
END
```

But it doesn't work, syntax error. I insert the trigger via phpmyadmin.

Comment: yes possible, so in other words when you run a trigger on certain table operation you can always do insert/update/delete on a different table provided that table does not have a trigger doing some DML on first table.
Provide some sample example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: `IF NEW.column1 <> OLD.column1 AND NEW.column1 = 'specific value'  UPDATE table2 ...`. You should post the CREATE statements for both tables and be more specific in your question, if you want a good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL trigger On Insert/Update events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975877/mysql-trigger-on-insert-update-events)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I've edited my initial message. I'm trying your suggestion but I'm unable to make it work. Sorry I have zero experience with triggers.

Comment: Do you want to update all rows in the `USER` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Increment 
AFTER UPDATE ON Subscription
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.State <> OLD.State AND NEW.STATE='C' THEN
        UPDATE USER
        SET num_sub=num_sub+1
        WHERE USER.id = NEW.user_id; -- change this condition as you need
    END IF;
END
```

This should also work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Increment 
AFTER UPDATE ON Subscription
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE USER
    SET num_sub=num_sub+1
    WHERE USER.id = NEW.user_id
      AND NEW.State <> OLD.State
      AND NEW.STATE='C';
```

Note: `NEW` and `OLD` refer to the row from the `Subscription` table which is being updated. `OLD` contains the values before the update. `NEW` contains the values after the update. So to check if the `state` has been changed you can compare `NEW.State <> OLD.State`.

Comment: USER.id must be the USER.id of the USER table or the SUBSCRIPTION table? (obviously there is a FK on subscription.userS which points to user.id). Thanks!!

Comment: It was just a quess, since you didn't provide the schema and the relation. Now change that line to `WHERE USER.id = NEW.userS`. BTW: `USER.id` means column `id` from `USER` table. `NEW.userS` is the column `userS` from the row which you have just updated in the `Subscription` table.

Comment: I just tried but it does nothing on the USER table. Maybe it's because Subscription.UserS points to User.id but it's not the primary key of the subscription table? If that's so, how can I resolve?

Comment: Well.. Provide CREATE statements for both tables and INSERT statements with sample data so I can test the trigger.

Comment: That was my mistake; the field num_sub was initialized to NULL. It seems to work fine. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JamieITGirl you can also change the line to `num_sub = coalesce(num_sub, 0) + 1`. This way `NULL` wil be "converted" to `0`.